# Book on characteristic classes

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

i am looking fo books on characteristic classes as main argument. I'd appreciate if you add a little comment on why you would study on it/them. Thank you.

Comment: why not add a reference-request tag?

Comment: Just edited thank you!

Comment: You probably need to indicate your background. Are you strong in algebraic topology, differential geometry, etc.?

Comment: Well i am mainly interested to their applications to complex differential geometry. I've already attended courses on basic algebraic geometry and riemannian/kähler geometry

Answer (score 7):

The following is a celebrated classic. J. Milnor is a Fields medalist, famous for the power of his mathematical thinking and the clarity and precision of his style.

*Milnor, John W.; Stasheff, James D.*, [**Characteristic classes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/9781400881826), Annals of Mathematics Studies. No.76. Princeton, N.J.: Princeton University Press and University of Tokyo Press. VII, 331 p. (1974). [ZBL0298.57008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0298.57008).

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Nefertiti: I would disagree. I love Milnor and his expository style, but I do not think about characteristic classes at all the way he develops them, and I've used them my entire mathematical career.

Comment: I like this book a lot, except the chapter that uses obstruction theory.

Answer (score 7):

For someone coming from the complex geometry perspective, I would suggest reading some combination of Chern (*Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory*), Wells (*Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds*), and particularly Griffiths and Harris. Only the latter discusses the important interpretation of the $j$th Chern class of a vector bundle of rank $k$ in terms of the locus where $k-j+1$ generic smooth sections of the bundle become linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Also D. Husemoller - *Fibre Bundles*, 3rd edition, part III is a good reference.

Comment: It's also worth looking at the true classic, Steenrod's  *The Topology of Fiber Bundles*.